# EC2 instance 'took too long to respond'

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have a site built on NodeJS, which I am currently trying to deploy on the free tier on AWS.

So far I have created an instance, launched it, I can connect via SSH (console) to my instance, and have successfully pulled my files from my Git repository. However, when I try to browse my public DNS, I get: **ec2-54-252-151-208.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080** took too long to respond.

I have also had a look at the settings on security group (as recommended on a different post) and ensured that inbound and outbound 'HTTP' and 'HTTPS' traffic are allowed (screenshot below):

Inbound settings:
[image: Inbound settings]

Outbound settings:
[image]

Any ideas on what else could be causing this issue? I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like you need to add port 8080 to your inbound IP rules.

Comment: You have no idea how grateful I am for your post !!! thank you !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just add the port 80 in inbound rules and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a rule in  ***EC2 > Security Groups >***
worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you stopped and then started your ec2 instance it gives you another Public DNS (IPv4). So you may be requesting old Public DNS without noticing it. In this case, you highly likely to get this type error!

Answer (score 1):

adding to @Rastamjon answer.
Your ip may change on restarting your instance. This can be avoided by taking an elastic ip and attacing it to your instance.
Read more about it here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Answer (score -1):

In case you are on windows RDP turn off your public firewall of the remote's machine.